# How do I create another object inside of a class

Tags: python, object

I'm making a simple game and I want to add another pickup but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
class Pickup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.width = 50
        self.height = 50
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
    def tick(self):
        if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect) == True:
            player.coincount += 1
            print("$" + str(player.coincount))

            overlapping = True
            while overlapping==True:
                self.x = random.randint(0, windowwidth - coin.width)
                self.y = random.randint(windowheight // 2 - self.height // 2, windowheight - coin.height)
                self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y,self.width,self.height)
                if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect) == False:
                    overlapping = False

        self.rect =pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(win, yellow, self.rect)
```

I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to add another tick or not.

Comment: You should add a language tag.

Comment: Can you expand on your question? "I want to add another pickup" is not enough for me to answer your question. Do you just want to create an instance of the pickup class by writing `pickup_one = Pickup()?`

Comment: I see you have a method named `tick`, but I still have no idea what you mean by "I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to add another tick or not". Put yourself in the shoes of somebody reading that sentence and trying to make sense of that or "I want to add another pickup but I'm not sure how to do that."